# mysql select not pulling any rows because of like %[$variable]% is messing up

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My mysql select query is getting 0 rows because of the values that are being put into the like statement. The example query is below:

```
$byear = '1975';
$search = "%205679%"; #example value

$query = $db->query("Select * FROM MDPay WHERE dobyear='".$byear."' and concat('|', PatID, FormatPhone, coalesce(' ' + cellphone + ' ', ' ')) like '".$search."'");

// result would be (0 rows) because the $search value converts the %20
```

This is returning (0) rows because the $search variable ends up being '5679' because the %20 is getting converted to whitespace. How do I keep php from converting it to whitespace?

I've tried using url_encode(), but I'm not sure how to keep it from converting the search value.

UPDATE: I have tried escaping the query, and I think the issue is PHP is parsing the %20 before it even get's sent through, so the values being sent to the query is '5679%'. How do I keep PHP from converting the value before the value is entered into the query?

Comment: Have you tried single quotes -> `$search = '%205679%';` instead of double quotes so that php does not parse before inserting into the query. Another idea is to escape the `%` -> `$search = "\%205679%";` so it treats it as literal, or add it later -> `$search = "205679";`/`'%".$search."%'`

Comment: You are using sql server concatenation,use `coalesce(cellphone, ' ','  ')`

Comment: I've tried using single quotes, and escaping. The example $search variable being used is a value from $_POST, so I can only parse through the value to add anything.

Comment: You're using PDO. That's great. Please **use placeholders** and do not do the quoting yourself. You'll get it wrong and you'll be in a [world of hurt](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the like function

```
$byear = '1975';
$search = "#%20#5679%"; #example value

$query = $db->query("Select * FROM MDPay WHERE dobyear='".$byear."' and concat('|', PatID, FormatPhone, coalesce(' ' + cellphone + ' ', ' ')) like '".$search."' escape '#'");
```

Comment: After trying this, the query is still getting sent to the server like this: Select * FROM MDPay WHERE dobyear='1954' and concat('|', PatID, FormatPhone, coalesce(' ' + cellphone + ' ', ' ')) like '# #27610%' escape '#'

Comment: Try this $search = "%#%20#5679%"; #example value

Comment: It's still removing the %20: "Select * FROM MDPay WHERE dobyear='1954' and concat('|', PatID, FormatPhone, coalesce(' ' + cellphone + ' ', ' ')) like '%# #5679%' escape '#'"